# V-data-table template v-slot syntax

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, tsx

Hello and thank you for reading my question.

I have an array of objects looking like this :

```
[{
  id=1,
  products= [a,b,c]
 },
 {
  id=2,
  products= [d,e,f]
 }]
```

I want to display data in a v-data-table with two columns (id and products) and products items in a nested v-data-table.

So far I found that i should use template and v-slot but I don't find the right way to do it.

```
<v-data-table            
        item-key="id"
        items={products}
      >
        <template v-slot="">
          <v-data-table> ... </v-data-table>
        </template>

      </v-data-table>
```

Instead of the nested table I get

```
[object Object],[object Object]
```

How to use template v-slot in tsx files ?
And more generally, how to 'translate' vuetify js to tsx (documentation) ?

Thanks again

Comment: Have you tried out the example which I provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have made a slot which is correct, but you need to tell vuetify which slot you want to access. To access the default `<td>` slot of all rows you can simply use `v-slot:body="{ items }"` and pass it the items, so you can create a view per column. (Available slots are listed here [Vuetify doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/), if you scroll down. Each component has them)

I have made a codepen that you can check out [Codepen](https://codepen.io/nicolasdurant/pen/dyOJrZV). As of translating it to tsx, I can't help you, since I haven't worked with it, but if you grasp the concept of how to do it on the vuetify part, you should be good!

Comment: Thank you for your answer Nicolas. We were successul in implementing nested data table with Vue. However we didnot succeed in translating it to TSX. We rollbacked to Vue since we haven't found much documentation on the subject.